# How to align collectionview cells right next to each other?

Tags: swift

I am creating a profile page screen for my application. The screen displays all the user's recent posts. I used storyboard to create two UICollectionViewCells in a UICollectionView, one that displays your profile info and the other that displays your posts. See this for how I designed it in storyboard: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TzwK.png

When I run the application, I get the following result: https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmvY3.jpg

However, I desire the cells placed in a way that it looks like the following: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWQ14.jpg

How do I force the cells the align so it looks like the image above? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found an answer to the question. Implement `UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout` delegate to your class. Then, include the following method into the class:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    let width = UIScreen.main.bounds.width // get the width of the screen
    let scale = (width / 3) // get the width (and height) of each cell

    if indexPath.row != 0 { // check to see if the cell is the profile header
        return CGSize(width: scale, height: scale) // if not, then return the cell size
    }

    return CGSize(width: width, height: ((238/414) * width)) // if it is the profile header, return the size for it.
}
```

Make sure "Min Spacing" for the UICollectionView's storyboard setting to 0,0. The cells will then align into a grid view.